# (Ubuntu bash script) Setting rights from a config txt

Tags: bash, ubuntu, config

I am a beginner and trying to write a script that takes a config file (example below) and sets the rights for the users, if that user or group doesn´t exist, they get added.

For every line in the file, I am cutting out the user or the group and check if they exist.

Right now I only check for users.

```
#!/bin/bash
function SetRights()
{

if [[ $# -eq 1 && -f $1 ]]
then
    for line in $1
    do
        var1=$(cut -d: -f2 $line)
        var2=$(cat /etc/passwd | grep $var1 | wc -l)
        if [[ $var2 -eq 0 ]]
        then
            sudo useradd $var1
        else 
            setfacl -m $line
        fi
    done
else
    echo Enter the correct path of the configuration file.
fi
}

SetRights $1
```

The config file looks like this:

```
u:TestUser:- /home/temp
g:TestGroup:rw /home/temp/testFolder
u:TestUser2:r /home/temp/1234.txt
```

The output:

```
grep: TestGroup: No such file or directory
grep: TestUser: No such file or directory
"The useradd help menu"
```

If you could give me a hint what I should look for in my research, I would be very grateful.

Is it possible to reset var1 and var2? Using unset didn´t work for me and I couldn´t find variables could only be set once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you are looping over the contents of the file -- if `$1` contains the file name, you should not be seeing the errors you report.

But anyway, here is a refactored version which hopefully avoids your problems.

```
# Avoid Bash-only syntax for function definition
SetRights() {
    # Indent function body
    # Properly quote "$1"
    if [[ $# -eq 1 && -f "$1" ]]
    then
        # Read lines in file
        while read -r acl file 
        do
            # Parse out user
            user=${acl#*:}
            user=${user%:*}
            # Avoid useless use of cat
            # Anchor regex correctly
            if ! grep -q "^$user:" /etc/passwd
            then
                # Quote user
                sudo useradd "$user"
            else 
                setfacl -m "$acl" "$file"
            fi
        done <"$1"
    else
        # Error message to stderr
        echo Enter the correct path of the configuration file. >&2
        # Signal failure to the caller
        return 1
    fi

}

# Properly quote argument
SetRights "$1"
```

Comment: useradd: invalid user name 'u:TestUser'

useradd: invalid user name 'u:TestUser1'

Comment: I think the u: before the name doesnt get cut out

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try more things you showed me the right direction

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I was thinking I should do the right thing but looks like my fingers typed the wrong thing anyway.  Updated now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try to add the functionality that groups can also be added on my own.